# IErrorDataInfo validation box is not visible

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a model and a UI

```
public class ModelObservable:ObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
{
    // ...some properties
    // ....
    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            result = "Always ERROR";
            return result;
        }
    }
}

<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
                 Text="{Binding Model.AnyProp, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

When I type into the textbox, the model setter fires, *IDataErrorInfo* event fires as well, but on the UI I don't see any red rectangle around the textbox.

I created a simple example in a separate project, just 1 property, 1 text box, and it works, but in my application it doesn't - rectangle around the textbox is blue.

**Update**
My main window is derived from Window and it causes the issue:

```
 public class CustomTitleBarWindow: Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowSystemMenuCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowSystemMenuCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomTitleBarWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public ICommand ShowSystemMenuCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(ShowSystemMenuCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(ShowSystemMenuCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimizeCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinimizeCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomTitleBarWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public ICommand MinimizeCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(MinimizeCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(MinimizeCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximizeCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaximizeCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomTitleBarWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public ICommand MaximizeCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(MaximizeCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(MaximizeCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CloseCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomTitleBarWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public ICommand CloseCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

When I change it back to Window, validation starts working. Why so?

Comment: I only worked with `INotifyDataErrorInfo` which works. Maybe try that? There isn't much difference between them

Comment: maybe somewhere you have changed the `ErrorTemplate`?

Comment: @krzysztof-skowronek no I just wanted to see the default red box

Comment: I know, but maybe the template is already overriden?

Comment: @krzysztof-skowronek I've checked.There's no Validation.ErrorTemplate overridden in the project. Any ideas? That's too wierd

Comment: try the notify version, otherwise I'm out :P

Comment: @krzysztof-skowronek could it be because of my textbox is inside item control?

Comment: nah, it should work

Comment: krzysztof-skowronek Ok found the root of the problem.My window is derived from Window. But why it causes the problem I don't know. When I make it "Window" the validation starts working. Please, see the update.